# focusing on input element when it's conditionally rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to focus on the input field as soon as it's rendered. The pitfall is that I can't focus on it in the startEdit method because there is no reference to the element at the moment I want to focus, so this.editField is undefined. I could probably create `<Input />` component and implement focusing in it's componentDidMount method but I wonder if there is a more concise way to do that?

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

        editField ?: HTMLInputElement;

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                isEditActive: false
            };
        }

        private startEdit(): void {
            this.setState({isEditActive: true});
            this.editField.focus();
        }

        private finishEdit(): void {
            this.setState({isEditActive: false});
        }

        public render(): JSX.Element {
            const {text, deleteTodo} = this.props;
            const {isEditActive} = this.state;
            return(
                <li className='todo-item'>
                    {isEditActive ?
                     <input ref={(input) => { this.editField = input; }} onBlur={this.finishEdit} type='text'/>
                      : text
                      }
                    <span onClick={deleteTodo} className='delete'>X</span>
                    <span onClick={this.startEdit} className='edit'>Edit</span>
                </li>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about using `autofocus` attribute on that `input` field?

Comment: Never heard of that attribute, thanks. Works perfectly now.