# React doesn't focus conditionally rendered input/textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, textarea

I'm trying to `focus()` a conditionally rendered textarea in React. The code below is almost exactly identical to the example in the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) or to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/react-set-focus-on-input-after-render).

The code below immediately shows and focuses the textarea. If the three commented lines are uncommented, the textarea gets shown after the `condition` prop is set to `true` (its value depends on the state of the parent and is initially `false`), but the element doesn't get focused anymore.

**If the condition is initially `true`, the input element gets focused as expected when the component renders for the first time. The problem occurs when the condition is changed from `false` to `true`.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class TestClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.focus = this.focus.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // this.props.condition &&
    this.focus()
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    // this.props.condition &&
    this.focus()
  }

  focus() {
    console.log(`this.textInput: ${this.textInput}`)
    this.textInput.focus()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          // this.props.condition &&
          <textarea
            ref={(input) => {this.textInput = input}}
            defaultValue="Thanks in advance for your invaluable advice">
            {console.log('textarea rendered')}
          </textarea>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The console output

```
textarea rendered
this.textInput: [object HTMLTextAreaElement]
```

rules out that the element is unavailable at the time `focus()` gets executed.

Furthermore:

- Setting `autoFocus` attribute doesn't seem to work, in contrast to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256652/focusing-on-input-element-when-its-conditionally-rendered)
- Same problem for both `<input />` and `<textarea />`

Edit: in response to the question below, the parent component looks as follows.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
    this.state = {
      condition: false
    }
    this.toggleCondition = this.toggleCondition.bind(this)
  }
  toggleCondition() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      condition: !prevState.condition
    }))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TestClass condition={this.state.condition} />
        <button onMouseDown={this.toggleCondition} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If you substitute your `this.props.condition &&` for a more verbose `if(this.props.condition) { }` in both componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate does this change the behaviour in any way?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. In JavaScript, `true && expression` always evaluates to `expression`, and `false && expression` always evaluates to `false`. (Source: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

Comment: Can you add your parent component code which is adding the TestClass component? I think the problem may lie in how you are passing 'condition' as a prop, if I pass it as a string using `<TestClass condition="true"/>`, it doesn't work, however passing condition as a boolean flag works for me: `<TestClass condition/>`

Comment: My guess is that the problem lies with the condition being initially `false`. If I set the condition to be initially `true`, it works. The condition is a boolean, but I will post the parent class in a minute.

Comment: I've tested your code in playground. `TestClass` updates properly as you expect. `this.focus` executes on every toggling. Maybe I got something wrong and didn't get the question. Can you provides some other details?

Comment: I'm seeing the same (as evidenced by the console output): `TestClass` updates and `this.focus` executes. What I don't see however is the textarea getting focus (with blue border / blinking caret) in Safari, Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: It's still strange because I see focusing in Chrome/Safari.

Comment: Is your condition initially `true`? The problem only manifests itself when the condition is changed from `false` to `true`. I've updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Nah, everything works properly in both cases. Anyway your code looks good, so it's really very weird that code doesn't work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149981/discussion-between-konstantin-yakushin-and-bart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was really really stupid. The way I implemented the toggle button (which I simplified to `<button onClick={this.toggleCondition} />` in the original question "for clarity"), was with a custom component which takes the `onClick` prop and attaches its value to the `onMouseDown` attribute of a hyperlink.

Because the hyperlink gets focused after its `onMouseDown` action, the focus was immediately taken away from the textarea.

I've edited the question to reflect my usage of `onMouseDown`.

Comment: What was the problem in my solution.

Comment: The problem was in the parent component. Your code worked independently from the parent component though. I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TestClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.focus = this.focus.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.focus();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.condition !== this.props.condition) {
        this.focus();  
    }
  }
  focus() {
    console.log(`this.textInput: ${this.textInput}`);
    if (this.props.condition === true) {
      this.textInput.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.condition &&
          <textarea
            ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
            defaultValue="Thanks in advance for your invaluable advice"
          >
            {console.log('textarea rendered')}
          </textarea>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default TestClass;
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this, `this.textInput` is `undefined` when `componentWillReceiveProps` gets called.

Comment: if this.textInput is undefined then this.textInput.focus() will not trigger.

Comment: Which is the problem :-)

Comment: Is that what you are expecting.

Comment: Please check the source.

Comment: If you defined any lifecycle method then they will excecute.

Comment: Note that `condition` is initially `false`. When I execute your code, first `componentDidMount()` gets called, at which time the textarea didn't render yet (due to the `condition` being `false`), and the console logs `this.textInput: undefined`. Then, after the `condition` prop is changed to `true`, `componentWillReceiveProps()` gets called but again skips `this.textInput.focus()`.